# Пунктуация со словом "нет" в значении "вернее"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, морфология, семантика, многоточие

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой частью речи является "нет" в данных предложениях (междометие или вводное слово в значении "вернее"?) и в каком из них пунктуация верна? Или оба варианта допустимы? Если возможно, приведите подобные примеры из литературы.

Касательно смысла: персонаж при помощи "нет" как бы поправляет сам себя, имея в виду, что бережливого типа скорее можно назвать просто жадюгой.

1. *Этот бережливый тип, нет, жадюга так меня достал, что усидеть на месте не могу.*
2. *Этот бережливый тип... нет, жадюга так меня достал, что усидеть на месте не могу.*

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить авторский вариант постановки знаков по слуху:

*Этот бережливый тип, **нет ― жадюга**, так меня достал, что усидеть на месте не могу.*

Вставка, обособленная запятыми (Розенталь разрешает), с уточняющим значением.

И разумеется, без примеров из литературы.